# C++ - Compilation error with Error class that inherit from std::exception

Tags: c++, exception, compilation, g++

Here is my Error class to handle errors with try & catch :

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>

  class Error : public std::exception
    {
    public:
      Error(const std::string&) throw();
      ~Error() throw();
      const char*   what() const throw();
    private:
      std::string           _msg;
    };
```

And the cpp file :

```
#include "Error.hpp"

Error::Error(const std::string& msg) throw()
  : _msg(msg)
{
}

Error::~Error() throw()
{
}

const char*     Error::what() const throw()
{
  return (_msg.c_str());
}
```

And I have this errors while compiling:

```
main.o:(.gcc_except_table+0x34): undefined reference to `typeinfo for Error'
MailBox.o: In function `MailBox::MailBox(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
MailBox.cpp:(.text+0x245): undefined reference to `Error::Error(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
MailBox.cpp:(.text+0x268): undefined reference to `Error::~Error()'
MailBox.cpp:(.text+0x270): undefined reference to `typeinfo for Error'
MailBox.cpp:(.text+0x2f0): undefined reference to `Error::Error(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
MailBox.cpp:(.text+0x313): undefined reference to `Error::~Error()'
MailBox.cpp:(.text+0x31b): undefined reference to `typeinfo for Error'
MailBox.cpp:(.text+0x3d6): undefined reference to `Error::Error(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
MailBox.cpp:(.text+0x3f9): undefined reference to `Error::~Error()'
MailBox.cpp:(.text+0x401): undefined reference to `typeinfo for Error'
MailBox.cpp:(.text+0x452): undefined reference to `Error::Error(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
MailBox.cpp:(.text+0x475): undefined reference to `Error::~Error()'
MailBox.cpp:(.text+0x47d): undefined reference to `typeinfo for Error'
MailBox.cpp:(.text+0x50a): undefined reference to `Error::Error(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
MailBox.cpp:(.text+0x52d): undefined reference to `Error::~Error()'
MailBox.cpp:(.text+0x535): undefined reference to `typeinfo for Error'
MailBox.cpp:(.text+0x6af): undefined reference to `Error::Error(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
MailBox.cpp:(.text+0x6d2): undefined reference to `Error::~Error()'
MailBox.cpp:(.text+0x6da): undefined reference to `typeinfo for Error'
MailBox.cpp:(.text+0x854): undefined reference to `Error::Error(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
MailBox.cpp:(.text+0x877): undefined reference to `Error::~Error()'
MailBox.cpp:(.text+0x87f): undefined reference to `typeinfo for Error'
MailBox.cpp:(.text+0x923): undefined reference to `Error::Error(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
MailBox.cpp:(.text+0x946): undefined reference to `Error::~Error()'
MailBox.cpp:(.text+0x94e): undefined reference to `typeinfo for Error'
MailBox.cpp:(.text+0x9b6): undefined reference to `Error::Error(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
MailBox.cpp:(.text+0x9d9): undefined reference to `Error::~Error()'
MailBox.cpp:(.text+0x9e1): undefined reference to `typeinfo for Error'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've already used this Error class for another project, and it worked well. I don't understand why here it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is **not** a compilation error, this is a *linker* error. Basically, this error is informing you that a definition for some your functions is missing.

Reading from the linker's output, it is evident that those functions are the copy constructor and the destructor of class `Error`.

This is compatible with the fact that you are showing just a declaration of those function (in the class definition for `Error`). You should also provide a *definition* for them. For instance, you could simply inline those definitions:

```
class Error : public std::exception
{
public:
    Error(const std::string& s) throw() : _msg(s) { }
    ~Error() throw() { };
    const char*   what() const throw() { return _msg.c_str(); };
private:
    std::string _msg;
};
```

Comment: @Elfayer: Then the `Error.cpp` file does not get processed by the compiler somehow. Check your project settings and make sure the file is not excluded from the build. Also, to verify if this is the issue, try inlining those function definitions as I suggested. If it works, then the problem is definitely that `Error.cpp` does not get processed.

Comment: Oh my god... I've forget to put Error.cpp on my Makefile. I feel sooo stupid ! >< Let's say I'm tired...

Comment: @Elfayer: It just happens, no worries ;)